# Check parent node if at least one child node is checked

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to check a parent node in a treeview if at least one child node is selected.

I've tried to add the control in an inner loop that set the Checked property to true if a child node is checked.

My treeView is 3-level. I want to check the second level node if a third level node (or nodes) is/are checked.

After a check to the third level, I want that the "check" char (✓) is SHOWN in the second level node treeview, dynamically and graphically on my windows form that contains the treeview.

How I can do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < treeViewMain.Nodes.Count; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < treeViewMain.Nodes[i].Nodes.Count; j++)
          for (int k = 0; k < treeViewMain.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes.Count; k++)
               if (treeViewMain.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes[k].Checked){
                            treeViewMain.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Checked = true; //HERE
                            DataTable dt = Util.selectChecked(treeViewMain.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes[k].Text);
                            DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                            if (row["id"].ToString().Contains("h") || row["id"].ToString().Contains("s")) nt = nt + 1;
                            n = n + 1;
                        }
```

Comment: How about using click event and handle it based on checked property?

Comment: @just-my-name the operations that I do after that, work! I only what that "✓" appears in the treeview graphically.

Comment: Have you tried setting `CheckState` property?

Comment: @just-my-name it works but I can't see the ✓ when I check a child node